# On iPhone, don't backup videos in a video app to iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, time-machine, backup, video

I've got a video app, [AVPlayer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/avplayer/id395680819?mt=8), on my iPhone. When I put videos in there, and then sync and backup to iTunes, the videos are also backed up. This can take up a lot of time and space to backup those videos.

How can I instead skip backing up files in AVPlayer specifically? The app, in fact, has a setting to disable backing up to iTunes, but the setting doesn't work for me because I've already got it disabled. Is there a way to control this myself, so that this app and its contents are not backed up to iTunes?

Comment: I'd contact the developers & ask why their switch might not be working.

Comment: Yep I contacted them a week ago but still have not heard back. The switch works fine on the iPad version of the app though (actually there didn't used to be a switch at all, and it didn't back up the files by default).

Comment: My guess would be it went in their jira [bug-file] & next you'll hear is that there's a new version that fixes it.

Comment: Perhaps, but it looks like [they've had this problem for at least two years](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1983024), unfortunately.

Comment: … which possibly means they don't know how to fix it, as yet. It's not something that can be dictated by the iDevice, as far as I know.

Comment: If I recall, an app can specify that certain data be considered cache, so it won't backup to iTunes. Like I said, the iPad version of this app does not backup its videos to iTunes, strangely enough.

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone go to Settings -> General -> Storage & iCloud Usage -> Manage Storage -> . Here you have Backup Options and you can select which apps to include in the backup.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Apple makes you do a full system backup so they can get all your data saved to their servers. This means all apps and all app data are copied to your computer through iTunes and a list of all your files is sent to Apple secretly every time you plug in the iPhone to your computer. Also it is Apple's marketing policy to make advance users suffer, while reducing basic users' confusions by providing less options all together. There are a lot of criticisms on Apple's user experience choices.